# How to count each word in each row python

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I have a dataframe

```
0       2021-03-19 20:59:49+06  ...  I only need uxy to hit 20 eod to make up for a...
1       2021-03-19 20:59:51+06  ...                                 Oh this isn’t good
2       2021-03-19 20:59:51+06  ...  lads why is my account covered in more red ink...
3       2021-03-19 20:59:51+06  ...  I'm tempted to drop my last 800 into some stup...
4       2021-03-19 20:59:52+06  ...  The sell offs will continue until moral improves.
```

And I want to count each occurrence of the word using counter and I want make sure that I count only strings
So I will begin with

```
Counter()
Then when word occurs
Counter(I:1,only:1,need:1....)
Then when it will see the same word the number would be added up to the previous number
```

Here is what I tried

```
import enchant
import pandas as pd
import string
from collections import Counter

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from stopwords import res

discussion = pd.read_csv('discussion_thread_data.csv', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
discussion = discussion.drop_duplicates('text')
discussion = discussion[discussion['text'].notnull()]
print(discussion)
# print(discussion)
d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
stop = stopwords.words('english')
word_bin = Counter()

def clean_word(word):
    res = []
    [res.append(c) for c in word if c not in string.punctuation]
    return ''.join(res)

def word_extractor(text):
    global word_bin
    words = text.split()
    words = set([clean_word(word) for word in words])
    words = [word for word in words if (word != '' and not d.check(word)) and not ['A', 'IM']]
    # words = d.check(words)
    word_bin += Counter(words)
    print(word_bin)

discussion.text.apply(lambda x: word_extractor(x))
word_bin = [word for word, cnt in word_bin.most_common(100)]

print('end')
print(word_bin)
```

but it keeps giving me Counter() for each row
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
from collections import Counter

import pandas as pd

# Toy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        ["2021-03-19 20:59:49+06", "I only need uxy to hit 20 eod to make up for a"],
        ["2021-03-19 20:59:51+06", "Oh this isn’t good"],
        ["2021-03-19 20:59:51+06", "lads why is my account covered in more red ink"],
        ["2021-03-19 20:59:51+06", "I'm tempted to drop my last 800 into some stup"],
        ["2021-03-19 20:59:52+06", "The sell offs will continue until moral improves"],
    ]
)
df.columns = ["date", "strings"]

# Initialize a counter object
records = Counter()

# Count words in "strings" column, row by row
for string in df["strings"].values:
    records.update(string.split(" "))

print(records.most_common(10))
# Outputs
[
    ("to", 3),
    ("my", 2),
    ("I", 1),
    ("only", 1),
    ("need", 1),
    ("uxy", 1),
    ("hit", 1),
    ("20", 1),
    ("eod", 1),
    ("make", 1),
]
```

Comment: How would you get rid of english words in this case?

Comment: So I want to get rid of words like to, I

Comment: This is a different question than the one you posted, but you could elaborate on my answer and add a condition in the for loop, before updating records, such as `if string not in english_stopwords:`, where english_stopwords is a list of the words you want to exclude.